# Downgrading iPad update

Tags: downgrade

I updated the iPad and the music app updated to different layout.
Can I return to previous update?
It is for my mother and she can't see. She could play music and now with the upgrade she can't use it. Just need to know if it is possible to go back to previous upgrade or even a few upgrades previous.

Comment: If you have a backup: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184